# Jank with Velocity

Tags: javascript, html, css, velocity.js

I'm trying to beat the junk on this page: http://mawo.olkusz.pl/ . Jank is only on mobile & basically on all phones, even on Samsung Galaxy 6. When page is "loaded", I hide initial blue screen with Velocity. Here's the code that does it:

```
  function fn_siteLoader() {
    var $siteLoader = $('.site-loader');

    $siteLoader.velocity({
      translateZ: 0,
      translateY: '-100%'
    }, {
      queue: false,
      delay: 500,
      duration: 1500,
      easing: [0.710, 0.100, 0.3, 1.000],
      complete: function() {
        $(this).remove();
        $body.addClass('is-loaded');
      }
    });
  }
  $(window).on('load', function() {
    fn_siteLoader();
  });
```

I tried numerous hacks, like `will-change` in wain. Also I didn't manage to get any insight from Google's Timeline. Any ideas why this simple animation is so janky? I've uploaded not minimized version of the page for debugging.

Comment: it's happening right after the first easing (iPhone chrome). Could it be the calculation for the easing is causing a large float?

Comment: @skobaljic The blue screen eases upward slightly, freezes, then eases upward quickly, slows, and moves off screen, after the page is loaded. I'm guessing the freeze is what the asker is referring to.

Comment: Well, looks same as on desktop Firefox. I suggest to use CSS animation and JS just to add the class. There is no need to animate with Javascript. Easing can also be defined in CSS.

Comment: Actually, once the page is cached, the easing freezing :) goes away. It must be rendering an image or something complex at that moment (images are loaded and sized before but rendered after window.onload is fired). Could be the Google map too.

Comment: Wow, google maps was the culprit - i put init code for it inside setTimeout (after 2seconds) and junk went away. If you put this as an answer i'll vote for it. Thanks for all suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If performance is a concern, I'd try doing this without Velocity, and even jQuery for that matter:

```
function whichTransitionEvent(){
  var t; var el = document.createElement('fakeelement');
  var transitions = {
    'transition':'transitionend',
    'OTransition':'oTransitionEnd',
    'MozTransition':'transitionend',
    'WebkitTransition':'webkitTransitionEnd'
  }
  for(t in transitions){
    if( el.style[t] !== undefined ){
      return transitions[t];
    } 
  } 
}

function fn_siteLoader() {
  var siteLoader = document.querySelector('.site-loader');
  siteLoader.classList.add('animating');

  var transitionEvent = whichTransitionEvent();
  transitionEvent && e.addEventListener(transitionEvent, function() {
    siteLoader.parentNode.removeChild(siteLoader);
    document.body.classList.add('is-loaded');
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn_site loader);
```

Then in your CSS you'll just need to add styles for '.site-loader' (obviously use whatever easing or timing function you want):

```
transition: transform 1.5s 0.5s ease;
```

And for '.site-loader.animating':

```
transform: translateY(-100%);
```

For production, you'll want to make sure and add any browser prefixes that are required to your CSS...plenty of tools and resources exist to automate that process if desired.

This should be pretty darn jank-free now, as we're using GPU-enabled CSS3 animations, and we've removed the need for about 65kb worth of dependencies in jQuery and Velocity.

Comment: Great snippet, i'll for sure use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a 0 second setInterval() in your window.onload event. This might seem hacky, but it has been used in the past to work around some other onload problems. It will create a separate thread, that, in multicore CPUs, will not freeze your animation while another rendering takes place. This might not work, however, but it's hard to test because I can't reproduce the problem on my own server, plus I'm not even sure how subjective the effect is.